# Is this relationship possible in CF9's ORM? How?

Tags: hibernate, orm, coldfusion, coldfusion-9

First, the relevant bits of the table structure:

```
contact
    -contactID
    -email

data
    -value
    -contactID
    -definitionID

definition
    -definitionID
    -name
```

Each record in the `contact` table represents a single contact along with their e-mail address.

Each record in the `definition` table represents the definition of a custom data field. For example, there might be five records in `definition` - Organization, Zip Code, Comments, Address, Phone. In addition to the names of the fields, it also defines relevant meta-data about the fields.

Each record in the `data` table contains the value of the custom data field as it relates to the contact. Its definition is taken from the `definition` table.

To further clarify, if I wanted to generate a table of contacts along with their custom field data, it might look like this:

```
| E-Mail            | Organization | Zip Code | Comments                         | Address       | Phone    |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| sean@example.com  | ACME         | 12345    | Cool guy!                        | 123 Test St   | 555-5555 |
| sean2@example.com | SomeCo.      | 54321    | Doesn't know anything about ORM! | 321 Test Blvd | 444-4444 |
```

The benefit of this system is that it can scale out as much as I need it to and is easily customizable. The detriment is that I have no idea how to define the relationships :)

I've attempted defining `contact:data` as `1:M` and `definition:data` as `1:M`, but the results seem a little odd: With two contacts and a single definition, adding a row to data for each contact and then calling `entityLoad( 'Contact' )` results in an interesting relationship. It appears like this(just going to use some pseudo-struct notation because it's easy enough to type and, I hope, read):

```
{
    contact: {
        email: 'sean@example.com',
        data: {
            value: 'ACME',
            definition: {
                name: 'Organization',
                data: {
                    value: 'SomeCo.',
                    contact: {
                        email: 'sean2@example.com'
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It looks like it is creating an indirect relationship between `contact` and `definition` based on the `data` table's relation to both tables. As you can imagine, upping the amount of contacts and custom fields just makes the problem exponentially worse.

Is this type of relationship possible using CF9's ORM? How can I accomplish it?

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: Forgot to specify - I am using MySQL, if it matters.

EDIT 2: CFC definitions follow:

**Contact.cfc**

```
/**
 * @persistent true
 */
component name='Contact' {

    /**
     * @type numeric
     * @sqltype int(11)
     * @generator increment
     * @fieldtype id
     */
    property contactID;

    /**
     * @type string
     * @sqltype varchar(50)
     */
    property email;

    /**
     * @type array
     * @fieldtype one-to-many
     * @cfc Data
     * @fkcolumn dataID
     */
    property data;
}
```

**Definition.cfc**

```
/**
 * @persistent true
 */
component name='Definition' {

    /**
     * @type numeric
     * @sqltype int(11)
     * @generator increment
     * @fieldtype id
     */
    property definitionID;

    /**
     * @type string
     * @sqltype varchar(50)
     */
    property name;

    /**
     * @type array
     * @fieldtype one-to-many
     * @cfc Data
     * @fkcolumn dataID
     */
    property data;

}
```

**Data.cfc**

```
    /**
 * @persistent true
 */
component {

    /**
     * @type numeric
     * @sqltype int(11)
     * @generator increment
     * @fieldtype id
     */
    property dataID;

    /**
     * @type string
     * @sqltype varchar(50)
     */
    property value;

    /**
     * @fieldtype many-to-one
     * @fkcolumn contactID
     * @cfc Contact
     * @inverse true
     */
    property contact;

    /**
     * @fieldtype many-to-one
     * @fkcolumn definitionID
     * @cfc Definition
     * @inverse true
     */
    property definition;

}
```

Comment: I believe you want to implement a many-to-many relationship between contact and definition with data as your "LinkTable": http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/Developing/WS5FFD2854-7F18-43ea-B383-161E007CE0D1.html

Comment: On second thought, I'm not sure how you would access the "value" field in "data" if you use it as the link table in a many-to-many.  Perhaps the correct approach is to define a one-to-many relationship between contact and data, and then a many-to-one relationship between data and definition.

Comment: @Danimal37 Thank you for your comments! As noted in my question, I defined both `definition:data` and `contact:data` as one-to-many and received the results above :)

Comment: It's been a while since I've worked with CF's ORM, but it seems that you can invert your relationship so that rather than `definition:data` as `1:M`, you can invert it to `data:definition` being `M:1`.  In other words, define your property with the relationship inside of `data` and not inside `definition`.  Of course, I am making assumptions here since I haven't actually seen your ORM CFC definitions.

Comment: @Danimal37 That's correct, you can invert the relationships using `@inverse true` or `inverse='true'`. I did try doing this, but I had no better results. I apologize for the lack of my CFC definitions - I don't have the code in front of me, but I will update the question when I get home from work tonight.

Comment: Sorry for the delay - CFC definitions have been added to the bottom of the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you want the relationships to be handled by Data.cfc, having

```
Data --m2o--> Contact
Data --m2o--> Definition
```

and for convenience

```
Contact --o2m--> Data (inverse=true)
```

**CFC's**

```
// Contact.cfc
component persistent="true" {
  property name="contactID" fieldtype="id" generator="native";
  property name="email";
  property name="data" cfc="Data" fieldtype="one-to-many" inverse="true" lazy="true";
}

// Definition.cfc
component persistent="true" {
  property name="definitionID" fieldtype="id" generator="native";
  property name="name";
}

// Data.cfc
component persistent='true'{
  property name="dataID" fieldtype="id" generator="native";
  property name="value";
  property name="contact" cfc="Contact" fieldtype="many-to-one" fkcolumn="contactID";
  property name="definition" cfc="Definition" fieldtype="many-to-one" fkcolumn="definitionID";
}
```

**index.cfm**

```
<cfscript>
ormReload();
transaction {
    con = new Contact();
    con.setEmail("chris@domain.com");
    entitySave(con);

    def1 = new Definition();
    def1.setName("twitter");
    entitySave(def1);

    def2 = new Definition();
    def2.setName("interests");
    entitySave(def2);

    data1 = new Data();
    data1.setValue("d1rtym0nk3y");
    data1.setDefinition(def1);
    data1.setContact(con);
    entitySave(data1);

    data2 = new Data();
    data2.setValue("ColdFusion");
    data2.setDefinition(def2);
    data2.setContact(con);
    entitySave(data2);

    // this is important, you must set both sides of the relationship or "bad things" happen
    // i'd recommend overriding contact.addData()/data.setContact to ensure both sides get set
    con.addData(data1);
    con.addData(data2);
}
writeDump(con);
</cfscript>
```

To retrieve the Data attributes for a Contact in a sensible fashion you can do

```
myData = ormExecuteQuery("
    select new map(
        data.value as value,
        def.name as name
    )
    from Data data
    join data.definition def
    where data.contact.contactID = :id

", {id=con.getContactID()});

writeDump(myData);
```

Comment: Nailed it, thanks! :) I was under the impression that the relationship had to be defined from both sides, which was probably my downfall in this situation.